# Azure API - AUTHENTICATING APIS WITH A CLIENT CERTIFICATE + OAUTH 2.0

Tags: c#, api, azure-api-management, client-certificates

I have implemented Oauth 2.0 Azure API Authentication by creating a token with Client Secret.
I am trying to use a Client certificate instead of a Client secret for creating OAuth 2.0 token.
Could you please guide me on how to use the Client certificate to get a token?
C# Code needed for implementing same.

Comment: do you already have the mechanism to generate oauth 2.0 token if the clients prove their identity ?

Comment: yes, I have implemented Oauth 2.0 using the Client secret key. I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 by Client certificate. Plz suggest way of implementation.

Comment: Hi, @Ukstest. Is there any update? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate). It shows how to get an access token with a certificate by the HTTP request.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=<client-id>
&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
&client_assertion=<An assertion (a JSON web token) that you need to create and sign with the certificate you registered as credentials for your application. >
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

**C#:**

**1. Use [`Azure.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme)**

```
// Authenticate a service principal with a certificate

using Azure.Identity;

var certificate = new X509Certificate2("./app/certs/certificate.pfx");
var credential = new CertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);
```

**2. Use `WithCertificate` in [`MSAL.NET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications)**

The blog: https://cmatskas.com/create-a-net-core-deamon-app-that-calls-msgraph-with-a-certificate/

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DaemonConsole
{
    public class ClientCredentialsAuthProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication msalClient;
        private readonly string[] scopes;

        public ClientCredentialsAuthProvider(AuthenticationConfig config)
        {
            scopes = new string[] { config.Scopes };

            msalClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(config.ClientId)
                .WithCertificate(ReadCertificateLocal(config.CertificateName))
                .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMyOrg, true)
                .WithTenantId(config.Tenant)
                .Build();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await msalClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                return result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting access token: {exception.Message}");
                return null;
            }

        }

        // This is the required function to implement IAuthenticationProvider
        // The Graph SDK will call this function each time it makes a Graph
        // call.
        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetAccessTokenAsync());
        }

        private X509Certificate2 ReadCertificateLocal(string certificateName)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;

            using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
                X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
                X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certificateName, false);
                cert = signingCert.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(c => c.NotBefore).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return cert;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I referred to your code and links. All your suggestions are very useful. I made some changes in the code for the C# web application and generated an access token.